# PineScript v5 : array.concat(id1, id2) with strings reverse id2

Tags: arrays, pine-script

I'm not sure if this is the good place to post. I just spotted a bug with array.concat(id1, id2) with strings .
When using array.concat on a string array, values of id2 are reversed.

When using on floats array, it doesn't reverse id2 values.

So, once you know that, you can just use array.concat(id1, array.reverse(id2))

example :

```
a = array.new_string()
b = array.new_string()

array.push(a, "toto")
array.push(a, "tata")

array.push(b, "titi")
array.push(b, "tutu")

array.concat(a,b)

label.new(bar_index, 0, text = array.get(a, 2))
//returns "tutu" which should be at index 3
label.new(bar_index, 0, text = array.get(a, 3))
//returns "titi" which should be at index 2

c = array.new_float()
d = array.new_float()

array.push(c, 1)
array.push(c, 2)

array.push(d, 3)
array.push(d, 4)

array.concat(c,d)

label.new(bar_index, 0, text = str.tostring(array.get(c, 2)))
//returns 3 as expected 
label.new(bar_index, 0, text = str.tostring(array.get(c, 3)))
//returns 4 as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, they should merge elements in the same order.

Meanwhile you can try a custom concat function:

```
array_concat(id1, id2) =>
    int id1LastIndex = array.size(id1)
    int id2Size = array.size(id2)
    for i = 0 to id2Size > 0 ? id2Size-1 : na
        array.insert(id1, id1LastIndex, array.get(id2,i))
        id1LastIndex += 1
```